# Accessing a cell within a named ranged WITHOUT using the Index function?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to access the cell of a named range which is just a column or a row without having to use a function such as `Index`. For instance if I have a column called `test_column` I want to be able to access the first cell by writing something along the lines of `=test_column.1`.

I'm hoping a method like this could also be 'dragged' so that the formula inside will automatically increment to the next cell within the column i.e. `test_column.1`, `test_column.2`, `test_column.3`, etc. Which won't happen if you are using `Index(test_column, 0, 1)` etc. I know I could have a reference to an index column within Index (i.e. `Index(test_column, 0, A1)`, but this makes the formula inside the cell less readable and intuitive and more verbose than I would like it to be!

I'm hoping something like this already exists or that it can achieved using VBA.

Many thanks!

Edit for clarity:

The reason I would like this feature is that I think it makes the formulas much more readable. For instance `=acceleration.1 * time.1 + initial_velocity.1` is much clearer than `=INDEX(acceleration, A1) * INDEX(time, A1) + INDEX(initial_velocity, A1)`.

Comment: Maybe you can consider using tables (Ctrl + T) - then you can use the column names within the formula or `@Acceleration` to refer to the current row of column ´Acceleration`

Answer (score 0):

If you use a table (`Insert` > `Table`) you can reference columns by their name. Based on your post I suspect this is the best solution to your problem (table-based formulae are usually much more readable). Excel will use table-based formulae automatically if you select table cells while editing a formula.

Note however that with tables you can only reference the entire column or the value in the named column that's in the same row as the formula you're writing. (I.e. there's no way to say "This named column, row 7).

Alternatively you could still use `index` but include a `match` formula for find the column number to use based on name rather than number. (index + match is a common pattern you should be able to find examples of on the internet).

Edit to include an example based on your example:

1. Create a table with columns `Time`, `Acceleration`, `Initial velocity`, and `Final velocity`.
2. Populate the first 3 columns with your data.
3. The formula in the last column will be "=[@Acceleration]*[@Time] + [@[Initial velocity]]"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is promising. However, I need to be able to reference the table data from outside the table in separate worksheets. Is is possible to reference the data from an external table in this way? 

For instance something like ```[table1@acceleration] * [table1@time] + [table1@initial_velocity]```.

Comment: Yes, you just need to make sure your formula is on the same row as the data you're using. In that case the references would look like "Table1[@acceleration]".

Comment: Many thanks, I'll experiment with this. I worry that it will be too inflexible, the requirement to be on the same row isn't great, for instance.

Comment: Yes tables are good if you've got genuinely tabular requirements (e.g. calculating that final velocity for every row), but in more complex situations index + match may be a better way to go. (You can actually reference a numbered row in a table from within VBA but that's too large a topic to explain here.)

Comment: I've just discovered that you can reference named ranges that are a single column or row with the ```@``` symbol and it references the cell that is on the same column or row as the cell it is being accessed from. You don't need to create a table. This is extremely useful!!! So you can just say ```=@acceleration * @time + @initial_velocity``` and as long as you are on the same row it will access the correct data. This is slightly more flexible than creating a table and means you don't need to use the square brackets.